# WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, send-transaction

When I am trying to send SOL using sendTransaction function it gives me below error

```
WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found
```

Code:

```
const sendSol = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!connection || !publicKey) { return }
    const transaction = new Web3.Transaction();
    transaction.add(
        Web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: publicKey,
            toPubkey: new Web3.PublicKey(creatorsAddress),
            lamports: event.target.amount.value * Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        }),
    );
    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    transaction.lastValidBlockHeight = latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
    
    sendTransaction(transaction, connection).then((sig) => {
        setTxSig(sig)
    });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/295/transaction-simulation-failed-blockhash-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing network to devnet. Previously, I was on mainnet-beta

Answer (score 0):

I see you are providing the recent blockhash in your code so the issue shouldn't be that and it could probably be with your network.